# Ubuntu 20.04 on Raspberry Pi 4 cannot install MicroK8s

Tags: server, raspberrypi, microk8s

I have installed on a brand-new RPi 4 an Ubuntu server 20.04 following the indications contained [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#1-overview).

I boot my system, it starts correctly, then I try to install MicroK8s following [Canonical's advice from here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-kubernetes-cluster-on-raspberry-pi#1-overview).

The suggested command

```
sudo snap install microk8s --classic
```

gives the error

```
error: snap "microk8s" is not available on stable for
       this architecture (armhf) but exists on other
       architectures (amd64, arm64, ppc64el).
```

Why is that? I can completely understand the meaning of such a message (no support for architecture), but why does that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, download the 64 bit version for raspberry

https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi

Recommended : Server LTS 20.4.1 : https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi/thank-you?version=20.04.1&architecture=server-arm64+raspi

Desktop 20.10 : https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi/thank-you?version=20.10&architecture=desktop-arm64+raspi

Server 20.10 : https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi/thank-you?version=20.10&architecture=server-arm64+raspi

the 32 bit version for raspberry use armhf (apparently not supported by microk8s)
the 64 bit versions use arm64

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the point: there are actually *different* Ubuntu server versions for the RPi, I didn't make sure to install the `arm64` one and I think I got the wrong one.